# Function within a select query is called n+1 times for n rows when called using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We have a oracle stored procedure (SP) in which we have a select query that makes a call to an internal function (which performs some addition or subtraction based on input params), say abc(). The issue is that when we run the SP directly using sql developer the SP returns the correct result but when we call the SP from a java application using jdbc it returns incorrect results (for the same input parameters).

On analyzing we found that the function abc() gets called n+1 times for n records. Any inputs why it's behaving differently depending on where it being called from?

Select query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
     count(1) over(order by col1,col2) as row_count,
     col1,
     col3,
     col4,
     abc(col4,col5,col6) AS balance,
     col6,
     col5,
     col2,
     row_number() over(order by col1,col2) rn
     FROM tableA ORDER BY  col1, col2 )
     WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

Function

```
FUNCTION abc(col4 IN NUMBER,
            col5 IN NUMBER,
                        col6 VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
IS

BEGIN

      IF col5='4' AND col6='XYZ' THEN
             global_value:=global_value + col4;
          ELSE
             global_value:=global_value - col4;
          END IF;

RETURN global_value;

END abc;
```

Sample Data

```
col1        col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
20200103    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200115    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200120    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200210    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200203    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200224    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200218    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200309    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200302    11      0       86.4    1       XYZ             
20200309    11      null    86.4    4       XYZ             
20200302    11      null    86.4    4       XYZ
```

Result jdbc call vs sqldeveloper run

```
(jdbccall)          (sqldev execution)
balance             balance
1213.6              1213.6
1127.2              1127.2
1040.8              1040.8
954.4               954.4
868                 868
781.6               781.6
695.2               695.2
608.8               608.8
695.2               695.2
608.8               608.8
522.4               695.2
608.8
```

global_value is global variable with initial value of 1300

Comment: What is the "correct" result in your mind?  What is `global_value`?  Is it actually some sort of global variable (I'm guessing a package variable)?  So the value the function returns on each execution is dependent on all the prior calls to the function?  If so, that is going to be highly dependent on the query plan the optimizer chooses which may change over time.

Comment: Maybe your function was called once as a part of dynamic sampling by optimizer. Is it  possible to get the same result without this function using analytic queries?

Comment: @JustinCave, yes global_value is a global variable. I added some sample data and based on that the expected final balance is 695.2

Comment: This is a very non-standard approach.  Even if it gets "fixed", it is going to be incredibly brittle.  When the plan changes tomorrow or next week or next month, the results are going to be "wrong" again.  Is there some reason that you have to use a function like this rather than using an analytic function in your query that would produce deterministic results?

Comment: Yeah, we are going with that approach now. But for this issue you think it's because of the plan? If so then why the results are consistently different depending on how the SP is called, any idea?